# Break <span>s into next line starting from the left (rtl language)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, right-to-left

I have some spans. They form a sentence:

```
<span dir="rtl"> word4 </span> 
<span dir="rtl"> word3 </span>
<span dir="rtl"> word2 </span>
<span dir="rtl"> word1 </span>
```

It's written in a language which goes from right to left. So the last span contains the very first word. Now everything is displayed correctly as long as the sentence is displayed in *one single line*.

HOWEVER: When the sentence breaks, it will break the usual way, which means that what is the first word of the sentence, is now in the next line.

How can I make my spans break down on the left, so that the first span moves down into the next line first?

Comment: I believe the problem is that you're thinking in ltr terms even though you're mark-up is saying rtl.  If you were actually typing in an RTL text editor the words would not be in the order you show them; they would look like `4drow 3drow 2drow 1drow`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. As I see it, my text editor settings should have nothing to do with this. Or am I mistaken? The actual words are, of course, written from right to left, but it's not in English in any case. However, the behaviour which is important here is that of the spans. The individual words are being displayed correctly.

Comment: I'm saying that you're looking at English, which is a LTR language, but trying to think of it as RTL. The actual order of the words, if represented in an array, would be `{ w[0]="word1" w[1]="word2" w[2]="word3" w[3]="word4" }` no matter what the language, but you are reversing them so that `w[0]="word4"` and that is not how it would be in an actual RTL language.

Comment: oh, that's what you mean. yes, of course, you are right! I thought you were talking about the letter/chars of the individual words & my text editor settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using flex:

```
<div class="container">
  <span> word1 </span>
  <span> word2 </span>
  <span> word3 </span>
  <span> word4 </span>
</div>
```

and the css style is like this:

```
.container {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row-reverse;
    -ms-flex-direction: row-reverse;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
```

it should be noted that the above css makes all Spans align to right. if you want to align the Spans to the left, add this statements to the ".container" css class:

```
-webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
-ms-flex-pack: end;
justify-content: flex-end;
```

Turning this into a stack snippet, with a width that will force wrapping and a background to see the container gives this:

```css
.container {
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: -webkit-flex;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-flex-direction: row-reverse;
            -ms-flex-direction: row-reverse;
            flex-direction: row-reverse;
            -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
            -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            }
.a-block-to-force-warping{
            max-width: 10em;
            background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="a-block-to-force-warping">
<div class="container">
    <span> word1 </span>
    <span> word2 </span>
    <span> word3 </span>
    <span> word4 </span>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

What you probably want is the following:

```
<div dir="rtl">
  <span> word4 </span> 
  <span> word3 </span>
  <span> word2 </span>
  <span> word1 </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I too was thinking this, so I tried it before posting, and it gives exactly the problem that George describes — "word1" is on the next line, not "word4". So I didn't post.

Comment: This was also my first thought. It did not work for me either.